# Creating tuple with allocator c++

Tags: c++, std, stdtuple

I'm learing tuples in C++ and for now I'm trying to create tuple using allocator from libcxx

```
template <class _Alloc>
LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
tuple(allocator_arg_t, const _Alloc& __a, const _Tp& ... __t)
```

for instance:

```
std::allocator<int> myAllocator;
std::tuple<int> t(std::allocator_arg, myAllocator, 2);
```

but seems string above called

```
template <class Alloc>
tuple(allocator_arg_t, const Alloc& a, const Types&...);
```

what should I change for this?

As well, there is one row that isn't clear for me:

```
 explicit
 tuple(_Up&&... __u)
```

how does this call?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your post is terribly unclear. What were you expecting to happen? What *exactly* happened instead? Help us help you by being descriptive. Adding a [mcve] will also help a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy, as I mentioned before, I'm trying to call `tuple(allocator_arg_t, const _Alloc& __a, const _Tp& ... __t)` constructor and I supposed that it will be called using `std::tuple<int> t(std::allocator_arg, myAllocator, 2);` For me, there isn't clear what `_Tp& ... __t` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look into your implementation's source and see

```
namespace std {

    // Other things
    
    template <typename ... _Tp>
    class tuple {
    
        // More things
        
        template <class _Alloc>
        LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
        tuple(allocator_arg_t, const _Alloc& __a, const _Tp& ... __t)
        // an implementation of this constructor
    
    };
}
```

That *is* the constructor that [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) names

```
template <class Alloc>
tuple(allocator_arg_t, const Alloc& a, const Types&...);
```

Your implementation has chosen to use names that are reserved for its use. What exactly those names are doesn't matter to the compiler.

> what `const _Tp& ... __t` is?

It's a parameter pack of elements to copy into the tuple. For `std::tuple<int>`, it is `const int&`, for `std::tuple<std::string, bool, char>` it is `const std::string &, const bool &, const char &`. `__t` is the name of the parameter pack. C++ allows templates to have different numbers of parameters.

> what about `tuple(_Up&&... __u)`?

That's overload (3)

> Converting constructor. Initializes each element of the tuple with the corresponding value in `std::forward<UTypes>(args)`.
>
> This overload only participates in overload resolution if `sizeof...(Types) == sizeof...(UTypes)` and `sizeof...(Types) >= 1` and `std::is_constructible<Ti, Ui&&>::value` is `true` for all `i`.
>
> The constructor is explicit if and only if `std::is_convertible<Ui&&, Ti>::value` is `false` for at least one `i`.

E.g. for `std::tuple<int> tup('a');`, `tup` would be initialised by matching `UTypes...` with `char`, and the first member would have the numeric value of `'a'` (97 on most platforms).

Note that there isn't much point in using an allocator-aware constructor for `std::tuple<int>`, because `int` is not a allocator-aware type. Those constructors exist for cases like

```
using statefully_allocated = std::vector<int, my_stateful_allocator<int>>;
my_stateful_allocator<int> alloc1 = /* something */
statefully_allocated source(alloc);
my_stateful_allocator<int> alloc2 = /* something else */
std::tuple<statefully_allocated, char> tup(std::allocator_arg, alloc2, source, 'a');
```

Where the `statefully_allocated` member copies the contents of `source`, but uses a copy of `alloc2` to allocate. the `char` member is just an ordinary `char`, `alloc2` plays no part in it's construction. See [Uses-allocator construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator#Uses-allocator_construction)

Comment: Thanks, those things made the business a little bit clear =) but what about `tuple(_Up&&... __u)`

Comment: Seems, I didn't get enought because I've just tried use `std::tuple<int> tup('a');` to call `tuple(_Up&&... __u)` but there is without any success.